# How to set images under each image in vertical and horizontal order?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to align the images and text in the vertical and horizontal order as below:

Expected Image:

[image: Expected Url]

I have used **display: flex** and **flex-direction: row** as well as **justify-content: space-evenly**

But I am getting this image as a result:

Result Image:
[image]

Suggest some ideas on how to align the items as per the first image.

Comment: can't you just use `width: calc((100% / 4) - eventual-margins)` and let the `flex` property align them?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using `text-align: center`, `margin: auto`, and `display: flex`. The `justify-content` property works together with `display: flex`, which we can use to center the image. For more details, check out [this link.](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-center-an-image-in-css/#:%7E:text=%20Centering%20an%20Image%20Horizontally%20%201%20Text-Align.,Just%20like%20we%20used%20the%20text-align...%20More%20) Hope that helped!

Comment: I think the text is causing the issue of alignment, rather than images, I already had tried this css properties @Programmer33

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a HTML table?

By using the columns and rows of the table, you could put all icons and text in order.

Find out more about the `table` tag at w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Using table structure is not a good idea, so I prefer either div with flexbox or grid

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row {display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex; -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; flex-wrap: wrap;}
.items {width: 20%; float: left; display: block; position: relative;}
.items img{width:80%; height: auto; margin: auto; display: block;}
.items p{max-width:90%;text-align: center; margin: auto; display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="items">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/change-user-male.png"/>
<p>lorem loremlorem lorem</p>
</div> 

<div class="items">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/doodle/96/000000/user-male--v1.png"/>
<p>loremlorem</p>
</div>

<div class="items">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/doodle/96/000000/cottage--v1.png"/>
<p>lorem</p>
</div>

<div class="items">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/office/160/000000/user-folder.png"/>
<p>lorem lorem lorem</p>
</div>

<div class="items">
<img src="https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/icon/collection-favorites.png"/>
<p>lorem</p>
</div>

<div class="items">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/doodle/96/000000/user-male--v1.png"/>
<p>lorem lorem</p>
</div>

<div class="items">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/dusk/64/000000/dog-house--v1.png"/>
<p>loremlorem lorem lorem</p>
</div>

<div class="items">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/doodle/96/000000/user-male--v1.png"/>
<p>lorem lorem lorem</p>
</div>

<div class="items">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/120/000000/house-lannister.png"/>
<p>lorem lorem</p>
</div>

<div class="items">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/64/000000/rental-house-contract.png"/>
<p>loremlor em lorem</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly
}
.flex-container > * { // flex-items
  flex: 0 1 160px;  // 160px is sort of the maximum width, change it to suit your situation
}
```

This will work perfectly if there's an equal number of items in the rows and columns, as in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `display:grid`? It has [good support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) in all current browsers and partial support in IE.

```css
.row {display:grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr)); align-items: center; justify-items: center; gap: 20px}
.items {width: auto; display: block; position: relative;}
.items img{width:80%; height: auto; margin: auto; display: block;}
.items p{max-width:90%;text-align: center; margin: auto; display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="items">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/change-user-male.png"/>
<p>lorem loremlorem lorem</p>
</div> 

<div class="items">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/doodle/96/000000/user-male--v1.png"/>
<p>loremlorem</p>
</div>

<div class="items">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/doodle/96/000000/cottage--v1.png"/>
<p>lorem lorem</p>
</div>

<div class="items">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/office/160/000000/user-folder.png"/>
<p>lorem lorem lorem</p>
</div>

<div class="items">
<img src="https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/icon/collection-favorites.png"/>
<p>lorem lorem</p>
</div>

<div class="items">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/doodle/96/000000/user-male--v1.png"/>
<p>lorem lorem</p>
</div>

<div class="items">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/dusk/64/000000/dog-house--v1.png"/>
<p>loremlorem lorem lorem</p>
</div>

<div class="items">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/doodle/96/000000/user-male--v1.png"/>
<p>lorem lorem lorem</p>
</div>

<div class="items">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/120/000000/house-lannister.png"/>
<p>lorem lorem</p>
</div>

<div class="items">
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/flat_round/64/000000/rental-house-contract.png"/>
<p>loremlor em lorem</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you get the answer to this eventually?